# Restrict REQ_NEXT_CHAR to content length in ncurses form field

Tags: c, ncurses

When allowing to edit a form field in ncurses, I would like to also allow cursor motion with the arrow keys. Which work great.

However, when `KEY_RIGHT` is pressed, I call `form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_CHAR);`, which allow the cursor to be moved past the end of the field content. Here's my (almost) minimal working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <form.h>



int main(void) {
    FIELD *fields[2] = {NULL};
    FORM *form;
    int ch, cont, err;


    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    curs_set(1);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    fields[0] = new_field(1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    set_field_back(fields[0], A_UNDERLINE);
    field_opts_off(fields[0], O_AUTOSKIP);
    field_opts_off(fields[0], O_NULLOK);
    field_opts_off(fields[0], O_PASSOK);
    set_field_type(fields[0], TYPE_ALNUM, 1);
    form = new_form(fields);
    post_form(form);

    cont = 1;
    while (cont) {
        ch = getch();

        switch (ch) {
        case KEY_LEFT:
            form_driver(form, REQ_PREV_CHAR);
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_CHAR);
            break;
        case KEY_HOME:
            form_driver(form, REQ_BEG_LINE);
            break;
        case KEY_END:
            form_driver(form, REQ_END_LINE);
            break;
        case KEY_BACKSPACE:
            form_driver(form, REQ_DEL_PREV);
            break;
        case KEY_DC:
            form_driver(form, REQ_DEL_CHAR);
            break;
        case KEY_ENTER:
        case '\n':
            err = form_driver(form, REQ_VALIDATION);
            if (err == E_OK)
                cont = 0;
            break;
        default:
            form_driver(form, ch);
            break;
        }
    }

    unpost_form(form);
    endwin();
    printf("entered: %s\n", field_buffer(fields[0], 0));

    free_form(form);
    free_field(fields[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I restrict the cursor motion of `REQ_NEXT_CHAR` to the actual content of the field?

Answer (score 1):

Personnally I compute effective length of a field by :

```
leneff=strlen(suppr_espaces(field_buffer(field[iet2],0),0));
```

where suppr_espaces is the following function :

```
// ==== suppr_espaces ====== suppress spaces in the end of a string =====
char *  suppr_espaces(char * chan,char cara) // the last space is replaced by
{  char *ptc=chan; size_t len,len0;          //.. the char cara 
     len0=len=strlen(ptc); 
     while(len>0 && ptc[--len]==' ')
        ptc[len]='\0';
     if (len && ++len<len0) ptc[len]=cara;
return chan; 
}   // fin de la fonction suppr_espaces
```

Then you could compare the position of the cursor with the variable leneff for not move the cursor of the right of your actual content of the field

Comment: That may work sometimes, but the result from `field_buffer` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated (so `strlen` may not give a good length).